# Can managed code impact instruction level parallelism?

Tags: c#, cpu-architecture

Is there any way I can impact Instruction Level Parallelism writing C# code? In other words, is there a way I can "help" the compiler produce code that best makes use of ILP? I ask this because I'm trying to abstract away from a few concepts of machine architecture, and I need to know if this is possible. If not, then I will be warranted to abstract away from ILP.

### Edit

You will notice that I do not want to exploit ILP using C# in any way. My question is exactly the opposite. Paraphrasing: "I hope there's no way to exploit ILP from C#"

Comment: This is really the wrong level of abstraction for .Net.

Comment: @DaveHillier: Hm? That is exactly what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention the specific techniques that you use, and ask if they still apply. Why do you care about ILP?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx

Comment: "I hope there's no way to exploit ILP from C#" Why???

Comment: @DaveHillier: I hope they mean so they don't have to think about it, and don't have to micro-optimize their C# source code.  And that they won't be missing out on performance by not thinking about the data dependencies in the code they write.

Comment: @PeterCordes this is over a decade old and it seems like my comments are the only ones left standing so this doesn't make sense without the things I was responding to.
Microoptimisation is fine in some limited scenarios so it could be a valid question if they have a specific scenario.

Comment: Equivalent phrases were edited into the question at some point.  But yeah I wouldn't be surprised if earlier comments had an even less clear and more weird version of that.

Answer (score 1):

ILP is a feature of the CPU. You have no way to control it. 
Compilers try their best to exploit it by breaking dependency chains.

This may include the .Net JIT Compiler, however I have no evidence of this.

Comment: Unless there's a `-ffast-math` equivalent for C# / .NET, compilers can't break dependency chains for you, you have to write source with multiple accumulators (like `sum0 += arr[i + 0]; sum1 += arr[i + 1]`, etc.) if you want ILP for reductions.  In other cases, different ways to implement some operations might be hard for an optimizer to see (or might not be equivalent for some case that's actually ruled out by other checks), or involve changes to your data layout (e.g. to store absolute instead of relative offsets.)

Comment: This is super old and a question that probably should have been closed. Implementation details of the .Net JIT have no doubt changed significantly several times over the years. Maybe AOT has some options with regards to this.

Answer (score 0):

You are at the mercy of the JIT when getting instruction level parallelism. 
Who knows what optimisations the JIT actually does? I would select another language, like C++ if I really need this.

To best exploit ILP you need to break dependency chains. This should still apply. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311347/instruction-level-parallelism-exploration).

However, with all the abstraction, I would doubt that it is still possible to effectively exploit this in but the most extreme cases. What examples do you have where you need this?

Comment: Thanks for this. You almost answered the question. If you read the question again, you will notice that I do **not** want to exploit ILP using C# in any way. My question is exactly the opposite. Paraphrasing: "I hope there's no way to exploit ILP from C#".

Comment: Why do you care? It should not matter, you are already abstracted away from the architecture. C# is compiled into IL which the JIT turns into your machine instructions. Your CPU will do what it wants ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is NO explicit or direct way to influence or hint to the .NET compiler in IL or C# to do this. This is entirely the compiler's job.

The only influence you can have on this would be to structure your program such that it would be more likely (although not guaranteed) to do this for you, and it would be difficult to know if it even acted on the structure or not. This is well abstracted away from the .NET languages and IL.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use ILP in CLI. So the short answer is No.

A bit longer:

I wrote a code for a simple image processing task before, and used this kind of optimazation to made my code a "bit" faster.

A "short" example:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
  const int ITERATION_NUMBER = 100;

  TimeSpan[] normal = new TimeSpan[ITERATION_NUMBER];
  TimeSpan[] ilp = new TimeSpan[ITERATION_NUMBER];

  int SIZE = 4000000;
  float[] data = new float[SIZE];
  float safe = 0.0f;

  //Normal for
  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

  for (int iteration = 0; iteration < ITERATION_NUMBER; iteration++)
  {
    //Initialization
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
      data[i] = 1.0f;
    }

    sw.Start();
    for (int index = 0; index < data.Length; index++)
    {
      data[index] /= 3.0f * data[index] > 2.0f / data[index] ? 2.0f / data[index] : 3.0f * data[index];
    }
    sw.Stop();
    normal[iteration] = sw.Elapsed;

    safe = data[0];

    //Initialization
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
      data[i] = 1.0f;
    }

    sw.Reset();

    //ILP For
    sw.Start();
    float ac1, ac2, ac3, ac4;
    int length = data.Length / 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
      int index0 = i << 2;

      int index1 = index0;
      int index2 = index0 + 1;
      int index3 = index0 + 2;
      int index4 = index0 + 3;

      ac1 = 3.0f * data[index1] > 2.0f / data[index1] ? 2.0f / data[index1] : 3.0f * data[index1];

      ac2 = 3.0f * data[index2] > 2.0f / data[index2] ? 2.0f / data[index2] : 3.0f * data[index2];

      ac3 = 3.0f * data[index3] > 2.0f / data[index3] ? 2.0f / data[index3] : 3.0f * data[index3];

      ac4 = 3.0f * data[index4] > 2.0f / data[index4] ? 2.0f / data[index4] : 3.0f * data[index4];

      data[index1] /= ac1;
      data[index2] /= ac2;
      data[index3] /= ac3;
      data[index4] /= ac4;
    }
    sw.Stop();
    ilp[iteration] = sw.Elapsed;

    sw.Reset();
  }
  Console.WriteLine(data.All(item => item == data[0]));
  Console.WriteLine(data[0] == safe);
  Console.WriteLine();

  double normalElapsed = normal.Max(time => time.TotalMilliseconds);
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Normal Max.: {0}", normalElapsed));
  double ilpElapsed = ilp.Max(time => time.TotalMilliseconds);
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ILP    Max.: {0}", ilpElapsed));
  Console.WriteLine();
  normalElapsed = normal.Average(time => time.TotalMilliseconds);
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Normal Avg.: {0}", normalElapsed));
  ilpElapsed = ilp.Average(time => time.TotalMilliseconds);
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ILP    Avg.: {0}", ilpElapsed));
  Console.WriteLine();
  normalElapsed = normal.Min(time => time.TotalMilliseconds);
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Normal Min.: {0}", normalElapsed));
  ilpElapsed = ilp.Min(time => time.TotalMilliseconds);
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ILP    Min.: {0}", ilpElapsed));
}
```

Results are (on .Net framework 4.0 Client profile, Release):

**On a Virtual Machine** (I think with no ILP):

True
True

Nor Max.: 111,1894 
ILP Max.: 106,886

Nor Avg.: 78,163619 
ILP Avg.: 77,682513

Nor Min.: 58,3035 
ILP Min.: 56,7672

**On a Xenon**:

True
True

Nor Max.: 40,5892 
ILP Max.: 30,8906

Nor Avg.: 35,637308 
ILP Avg.: 25,45341

Nor Min.: 34,4247 
ILP Min.: 23,7888

Explanation of Results:

In Debug, there is no optization applyed by the compiler, but the second for loop is more optimal than the first so there is a significant difference.

The answer seems to be in the results of the execution of Release mode builded assemblies. The IL compiler/JIT-er make it's best to minimize the performance counsumption (I think even ILP). But whether you make a code like the second for loop, you can reach better results in special cases, and second loop can overperform the first one on some achitectures. But

> You are at the mercy of the JIT

as mentioned, sadly. Sad thing there is no mention of implementation could define more optimization, like ILP (a short paragraph can be placed in the specification). But they can not enumerate every form of architectural optomizations of code, and CLI is on a higher level:

> This is well abstracted away from the .NET languages and IL.

This is a very complex problem to answer it only experimental way. I don't think we could get much more precise answer a way like this. And I think the Question is missleading becuse it isn't depending on C#, it depends on the implementation of CLI.

There could be many influencing factors, and it makes hard to answer correctly a question like this thinking about JIT until we think it as Black Box.

I found things about loop vectorization and autothreading on page 512-513.:
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf

I think they don't specify explicitly how the JIT-er need to behave in cases like this, and impelenters can choose the way of optimization. So I think you can impact, if you can write more optimal code, and JIT will try to use the ILP if it is possible/implemented.

I think because they don't specify, there is a possibility.

So the answer seems to be No. I belive you can't abstract away from ILP in the case of CLI, if the specification doesn't say it.

**Update**:

I found a blog post before, but I haven't found it until now:
http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/
Example four contains a short, but proper answer for your question.

Comment: Your simple loop has no serial dependencies between iterations (unlike e.g. `sum += arr[i]` or a dot product), so there's nothing stopping the compiler from unrolling it for you the way you did manually.  (Unlike floating point, the integer loop-counter math can be transformed without changing the results.)  What you're showing is just manual unrolling, which might be helping due to front-end throughput, not helping out-of-order exec.  (Also, division was barely pipelined in CPUs in 2013, so that's a terrible operation to test ILP with.  Also ternary conditions might be branchy.)

Comment: Code like a dot product is much more likely to show speedups from using multiple accumulators: [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113527)